# Bluetooth receiver

Tags: android, bluetooth

So I got a [Bluetooth receiver](https://www.ebay.com/itm/3-5mm-Wireless-Bluetooth-Audio-Stereo-Adapter-Car-AUX-Home-Music-Receiver-Dongle/162529207457?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&var=461533634977&_trksid=p2060353.m2749.l2649) from ebay. According to the seller Bluetooth specification：Bluetooth V4.1+EDR Chip solution：CSR8635

How can I verify its 4.1 or the chip version through bluetooth?
Min SKD version 21.

There are 5 buttons on it.
Can I connect to it and get the button events only but not the audio connection?

I understand if you dont have time to write me an article. If you can point me to an article or a github source It would be much appreciated. Need something more specific then Android bluetooth dev guides. Pls do not down vote link only answers( I get down voted all the time :/)